# Apple Mac Pro Tower — can't remove CD in optical drive

Tags: macos

When trying to see if VMWare's Hypervisor would work with my Apple Mac Pro, I installed the CD and rebooted with the intent of installing the Hypervisor. (VMWare's compatibility matrix does say that VMWare will work with Apple Mac Pro systems.) Alas, when booting from the VMWare Hypervisor CD, it does not install.

Unfortunately, I also can't get the CD to eject because the system never boots into any operating system.

How do I change the boot order so that my Mac Pro will not try to install/run from the optical drive? In other words, how do I get the CD out of the optical drive? (I am not using a Apple keyboard -- otherwise I could try the "Option" key).

(With Wintel systems their optical drives can be manually opened via a hole in the front of the drive and the use of a paperclip. I don't have such a option with the Apple Mac Pro optical drive -- there is no hole.)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Apple, but on other systems, restart the computer and hit the eject button on the drive as soon as it has power.  If you're fast, you can grab the disk before the tray retracts.  Otherwise, grab the tray when it opens and hold it open while you get the disk.

Comment: Doing as I'm told (deleted my answer for a comment)... fairly ridiculous but meh: anyway: To eject using a Windows/PC keyboard: Hold down F12 as you restart the computer until the CD ejects itself. Mac "Option" key: On a generic USB keyboard the `Alt` key works as the Mac `Option` key.

Comment: Holding the mouse button down [& keep held] at the chimes should do it, on Mac. [& actually, there is a hole, it's just behind & slightly below the metal sliding gate , hold it to one side manually & you can maybe poke a paperclip in.]

Comment: On older OS's for apples you could drag a CD to the trashcan. Rather than doing the logical thing (delete it) it ejected floppies and CD's. Might be worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

You can try holding down the space bar while booting up.

Other option is to open the side and pull the DVD drive caddy out and using a paperclip or similar there is normally a little hole which you can push in which will force the draw open to remove the CD.

Comment: `normally a little hole which` See OP's post.